# Alternatives to @EntityRepository from typeorm

Tags: typescript, repository, backend, typeorm

In the following code, ive been getting an error in the line "const SettingRepository = getCustomRepository(SettingsRepository)" where it says that "SettingRepository" is being used before its declaration:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { getCustomRepository } from "typeorm";
import { SettingsRepository } from "./src/repositories/SettingsRepositories";

const routes = Router();

routes.post("/settings", (request, response) => {
    const SettingsRepository = getCustomRepository(SettingsRepository)
})

export { routes };
```

And i think that this is happening because of the "@EntityRepository" that i used in this other code, and there it says that this function is deprecated:

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { Setting } from "../entities/Setting";

@EntityRepository(Setting)
class SettingsRepository extends Repository<Setting>{

}

export { SettingsRepository }
```

I already looked it up and I found some solutions, some didnt worked and some i havent got to try because it seemed quite complex.
I wanted to know if there is a simple solution to this or if I can go back to the typeorm version that this function was still in use and what was that version.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown because the assigned variable and import method name from the `typeorm` both have the same name, so you can change it to another name.

```js
const settings = getCustomRepository(SettingsRepository)
```

and I recommend you use the latest version of `typeorm` and avoid using deprecated methods for such issues.

No need to decorate your class with `EntityRepository`. if there is a case that you want to implement custom repository, find it [here](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/custom-repository#custom-repository-extends-standard-abstractrepository).